# How to inherit class properties

Tags: inheritance, coldfusion

I have a CFC that is extending another CFC, and I want to inherit the properties from the super CFC. I am using the extends attribute, but my subclass is not inheriting the properties, however it is inheriting the methods. Both CFCs have `accessors="true"`. I've tried using `accessors="false"` in the subclass, but that doesn't work. What I mean by that is when I run the sets in the test page and dump variables.subclass.getResponse() it returns {} instead of a JSON string with the properties and their values (expected response below). I really don't want to have to duplicate the property declarations in my subclass. I tested on both ColdFusion 9 and Railo 4.2.1.

Actual output:

```
{}
```

Expected output:

```
{"success":false,"errorCode":"1","successMessage":"","errorDetail":"","statusCode":"200","errors":[],"data":"","requestDurationInMilliseconds":"0","errorMessage":"","statusText":"OK"}
```

Sample code below:

**superclass.cfc**

```
<cfscript>
component accessors="true" {
    property name="data" type="any" required="false" getter="true";
    property name="errorCode" type="numeric" required="false" getter="true";
    property name="errorDetail" type="any" required="false" getter="true";
    property name="errorMessage" type="string" required="false" getter="true";
    property name="errors" type="array" required="false" getter="true";
    property name="requestDurationInMilliseconds" type="numeric" required="false" getter="true";
    property name="statusCode" type="numeric" required="false" getter="true";
    property name="statusText" type="string" required="false" getter="true";
    property name="success" type="boolean" required="false" getter="true";
    property name="successMessage" type="string" required="false" getter="true";

    this.setData("");
    this.setErrorCode(0);
    this.setErrorDetail("");
    this.setErrorMessage("");
    this.setErrors([]);
    this.setRequestDurationInMilliseconds(0);
    this.setStatusCode(200);
    this.setStatusText("OK");
    this.setSuccess(true);
    this.setSuccessMessage("");

    public superclass function init() {
        return this;
    }

    public function getResponse( string format="json" ) {
        if ( structKeyExists(arguments,"format") and arguments.format is "json" ) {
            return serializeJSON(this); 
        }
        else {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
</cfscript>
```

**subclass.cfc**

```
<cfscript>
component accessors="true" extends="superclass" {
    // property name="data" type="any" required="false" getter="true";
    // property name="errorCode" type="numeric" required="false" getter="true";
    // property name="errorDetail" type="any" required="false" getter="true";
    // property name="errorMessage" type="string" required="false" getter="true";
    // property name="errors" type="array" required="false" getter="true";
    // property name="requestDurationInMilliseconds" type="numeric" required="false" getter="true";
    // property name="statusCode" type="numeric" required="false" getter="true";
    // property name="statusText" type="string" required="false" getter="true";
    // property name="success" type="boolean" required="false" getter="true";
    // property name="successMessage" type="string" required="false" getter="true";
}
</cfscript>
```

**test page**

```
<cfscript>
    variables.subclass = new subclass();
    variables.subclass.setSuccess(false);
    variables.subclass.setErrorCode(1);
    writedump(getMetaData(variables.subclass));
    writedump(variables.subclass);
    writedump(variables.subclass.getResponse());
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Don't us this.setpropertyname() just use setpropertyname()

Comment: Or...you could use `variables.propertyname`. Also, when you are setting default values, you should do that in the `init()` method.

Comment: So what do you mean by doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: @SeanCoyne Sorry, what I meant by not working is when I run the sets in the test page and dump variables.subclass.getResponse() it returns {} instead of a JSON string with the properties and their values. I'll update my original post.

Comment: according to your code, calling `getResponse()` with no arguments, should return the CFC instance.  You are returning `this` if there is no format argument or if the format argument is anything other than "json"

Comment: `this` inside a component is a reference to the instance of the CFC.  It appears, you want to serialize the data stored in the CFC which would be the `variables` scope.  However, I wouldn't replace `this` with `variables` because the variables scope also includes all the methods of the CFC.  Really, you should build a new struct, using the getters, and the serialize that to JSON and return it.  If no format, or non-json format is specified, you would just return that struct.  Forget about trying to use `this` or `variables`.

Comment: @SeanCoyne The format argument is defaulted to JSON so by default getResponse actually returns serializeJSON(this). I agree with you that building another struct based on the getters and then serializing that would work, but that seems to be a bit of a hack. If I uncomment out the property declarations in subclass.cfc it works as expected. I'm just confused why that is necessary.

Comment: You're right its defaulted, but `this` in this case refers to the subclass.  Those properties are defined on the superclass so `this` has no properties.  Again, you are misunderstanding how the `this` and `variables` scopes work in a CFC.  What you are trying to do is the hack.  `this` is the instance of the CFC.  You normally no not reference `this` from within the CFC itself (see my first comment).  Internally, you typically reference the `variables` scope.  However, doing what you are trying to do (serialize just the property data) you will be unable to use just the `variables` scope as-is.

Comment: fyi `<cfdump>` could be misleading as it hasn't been reliably shows all the properties you've inherited.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0ac4a-7fbc.html#WS23852758-A5D0-4c6b-AB17-5E03CBF885AE):

> Component inheritance lets you import component methods and properties from one component to another component. Inherited components share any component methods or properties that they inherit from other components, and ColdFusion initializes instance data in the parent CFC when you instantiate the CFC that extends it.

Given this, I didn't understand why a subclass wouldn't contain the properties of the parent component;  It seems counter intuitive to me. I, like you, expected the serialization to include all the parent properties and the child properties. So I played around with your example.

The properties of the parent component seem to act like Java private properties, and are not exposed to the child component, only the accessors are. Since the auto generated accessors store the value into the objects variables scope in CFML, the child has full accesses to the values stored by the parent accessors.

The issue in your original code originated form how the `serializeJSON()` function works. The serializeJSON function seems to only serializes properties of the passed component. Your subclass has no properties representing the values set by the parents accessors thus serializeJSON returns `{}`.

While playing around with your class structure the workaround I came up with for your getResponse() method was to create a custom method to expose the components properties along with its parents properties as a struct. I serialize the struct return from this method instead of the object itself (as suggested by Sean in the comments). In the child component I overridden the method to append custom properties of the child component onto the parents properties. I'm unsure how well this overriden method will scale with more complex data structures.

**SuperClass.cfc**

```
component accessors="true" {
    property name="data" type="any";

    public superclass function init() {
        data = "Super Class Value";
        return this;
    }

    public function getResponse( string format="json" ) {
        if ( structKeyExists(arguments,"format") and arguments.format is "json" ) {
            return serializeJSON(getProperties());
        }
        else {
            return getProperties();
        }
    }

    public struct function getProperties(){
        return {
            "data" = data
        };
    }
}
```

**SubClass.cfc**

```
component accessors="true" extends="superclass" {
    property name="subData" type="any";

    public subClass function init() {
        // Could use super.init() to pull parent defaults
        data = "Sub Class Value";
        Subdata = "Sub property";
        return this;
    }

    public struct function getProperties(){
        local.properties = super.getProperties();
        structappend(local.properties,{
            "subData" = subData
        });
        return local.properties;
    }
}
```

**Test.cfm**

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfset superclass = new superclass()>
    <cfset subclass = new subclass()>
    super class
    <br />
    #serializejson(superclass)# // Has one properties to serialize on
    <br />
    GetResponse with custom function:
    <br />
    #superclass.getResponse()# // Displays one property
    <br /><br />
    sub class
    <br />
    #serializejson(subclass)# // One property to serialize
    <br />
    GetResponse with custom function:
    <br />
    #subclass.getResponse()# // Two properties serialized
</cfoutput>
```